# Get taggable friends Facebook Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, gson, facebook-friends

How can I improve this code?

**Parse Facebook GraphObject using gson**

I was working on Facebook taggable friends, I Have parsed the GraphObject may be helpful to others.

**Parse Taggable friends function :: user_friends permission required**

```
public void getTaggableFriends(){
    Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(activeSession.getState().isOpened()){
    new Request(
            activeSession,
            "/me/taggable_friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    
                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                    if (graphObject != null) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                        String taggableFriendsJson = jsonObject.toString();
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        TaggableFriendsWrapper taggableFriendsWrapper= gson.fromJson(taggableFriendsJson, TaggableFriendsWrapper.class);

                    }else {
                        // do something
                    }
                    //response.get
                    
                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();
    }
}
```

**TaggableFriendsWrapper.java**

```
   public class TaggableFriendsWrapper {
    
    private ArrayList<TaggableFriends> data;
    private Paging paging;
    
    public ArrayList<TaggableFriends> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<TaggableFriends> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    public Paging getPaging() {
        return paging;
    }

    public void setPaging(Paging paging) {
        this.paging = paging;
    }

    public class Paging {
        
        private Cursors cursors;
        public Cursors getCursors() {
            return cursors;
        }

        public void setCursors(Cursors cursors) {
            this.cursors = cursors;
        }
    }
    
    public class Cursors {
        private String after;
        private String before;
        
        public String getAfter() {
            return after;
        }
        public void setAfter(String after) {
            this.after = after;
        }
        public String getBefore() {
            return before;
        }
        public void setBefore(String before) {
            this.before = before;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**TaggableFriends.java**

```
    public class TaggableFriends {
    
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Picture picture;
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Picture getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }
    public void setPicture(Picture picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    public class Picture {
        
        private Data data;

        public Data getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(Data data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
    
    public class Data {
        
        private String url;
        private boolean is_sillhouette;
        
        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }
        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
        public boolean isIs_sillhouette() {
            return is_sillhouette;
        }
        public void setIs_sillhouette(boolean is_sillhouette) {
            this.is_sillhouette = is_sillhouette;
        }
    }
    
        
}
```

**Facebook taggable friends sample response**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "picture": {
                "data": {
                    "url": "dummy_url.jpg",
                    "is_silhouette": false
                }
            },
            "id": "AaJfT2z9C1_tj00pdLMtmCSpsX70e_Hreb4xrY94jzK_lJOK5H9H16jjtZPnUPeyFWSszXZtY5mtA-FBkYaPJ24AV9X-8SXGc7_OxXjVBoCA",
            "name": "John Smith"
        },
        {
            "picture": {
                "data": {
                    "url": "dummy_url.jpg",
                    "is_silhouette": false
                }
            },
            "id": "AaK6xdBkzhkSOtr4C1NOI6TiqU4AUr6wzAFVh6KOivnmYqmOHCY_ThHqiC8Pw-2mOElasdLCCDgMvsmSN-dUaGmXpeEKl6Rtq_HMiZw9hAVMmdpOw",
            "name": "Tom Jerry"
        },
        {
            "picture": {
                "data": {
                    "url": "dummy_url.jpg",
                    "is_silhouette": false
                }
            },
            "id": "AaLlnBhsYq4uXpCob_xz8iEToLXf8au_10cBhNVqpJSoJAriDUOefS_w_cc9pg2wPkyasdo5sha75EwhmwJ1HjlVhtkC8e8mSi57F8v1Eo2U_GM6w",
            "name": "Tabour Michael"
        },
        {
            "picture": {
                "data": {
                    "url": "dummy_url.jpg",
                    "is_silhouette": false
                }
            },
            "id": "AaL3P25QKM7pcdRGasRhq3YwK4ijlKutMOErBdUiAqW9Nw2hXqMfk42gBb-T15szRIG38aUyZgaJwgfQ4mI_3vDCQbm0GkSPA7ZmEfVi3My72k4w",
            "name": "Robert Paul"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "after": "QWFMS2ZzRnV1eFNyZzloRW1JNElCcFVUckFJY0hTVll6QXk1QUlObHYtbkJVRW9fdmZ4NTdrV1ZLa3RYUEIzLWw4M1RSTVFsZ0xnOGtLVGRycTVab3lnZnlhaEVQS05RcXpxdXFBWHk3U3VpY3c=",
            "before": "QWFLckx0Z29jNExEUnFSTHF1NXVpNWZrTVVEb1dnajNNTHBRdmlHbjB6MUZpYXZWaXo0cUtqenRFOVFtaTdJSVZBaV84NkpfMGZDZlQ3X0RPT0dwSmhyRFU4M1JtMUgtZU9PMHpSdzFSSXVoQnc="
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();  getting graph object as null inside onComplete after execution of  .executeAsync();

Comment: Your facebook session is active ?

Comment: @FarazAhmed, Can you please know me how to get friend id from here give "id": "AaLlnBhsYq4uXpCob_xz8iEToLXf8au_10cBhNVqpJSoJAriDUOefS_w_cc9pg2wPkyasdo5sha75EwhmwJ1HjlVhtkC8e8mSi57F8v1Eo2U_GM6w",

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer, The Above use of api always return information of friends to developer,
Try to loging using developer credentials of facebook and you willl get fried list.
Sumbit app for the facebook review and after get reviewd by facebook. Every app user can enlist his/her fiends.